# jQuery Change Opacity as window is resized

Tags: jquery, window, opacity

I am trying to get the same effect as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/161/

```
    $(function(){
    var $win = $(window),
    w = 0,h = 0,
    opacity = 1,
    getWidth = function() {
        w = $win.width();
        h = $win.height();
    };

    $win.mousemove(function(e) {
        getWidth();
        opacity = (e.pageX/w * 0.5) + (e.pageY/h * 0.5);
        console.log(opacity);
        $('#myElement').css('opacity',opacity);

    });
});
```

But instead of opacity changing as the mouse moves further away, the opacity changes based on the width of the window. I do not want to use animation triggers based on window size to do this. I am looking to do exactly what is in the link above, but instead of mouse position it is window width. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have tried so many things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#myElement').css('opacity', $(this).width()/1000);
});
```

You can change `1000` to whatever you want. This number will be the width where the element will have `opacity: 1`.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/281/

Comment: ~ Thank you, very concise! Could you explain to me how to do the opposite? For example the opacity would get lighter as the window width got wider?

Comment: Simply, put the window width in the denominator of the equation, like this: `1000/$(this).width()` or `100/$(this).width()`. Feel free to experiment with the numerator. Remember that when window width is zero you'll get an exception (division by zero). It is very rare to have zero window width but good to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    var w = $(window).width();
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        $('#myElement').css('opacity', ($(this).width() / w).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/282/)

starts at full opacity and fades out as the window is resized down

Comment: Elegance is hidden in simplicty.

Comment: But what if window.height() change. I think start with [initial width*height] and while resizing compare it with [active width*height] would solve problem.

Comment: @OzgurEffe - Who knows, the question states "but instead of mouse position it is window **width**" ??